# Kendo UI - Ajax MVC - JSON always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid that has been sort-enabled. I want to do an ajax postback using jQuery to send the sort information to the action method to do some action.

```
var datasource = $(".data-table").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportToPDf", "MyController")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { sort: datasource._sort } 
});
```

I'm able to see with a `debugger` that the correct value is got and passed in the data attribute of the ajax. I used FireBug to confirm that the values are passed during the POST action.

```
public ActionResult ExportToPDf(List<SortDescription> sort)
{
    //Will be doing some action
    return null;
}

public class SortDescription
{   
    public string dir { get; set; }
    public string field { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data from Firebug during POST action

```
sort[0][dir]    asc
sort[0][field]  EmployeeRef
```

When I keep breakpoint in action method, **im able to get one item in the list, but the properties appear to be null.**

Can anyone please guide me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportToPDf", "MyController")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({sort: datasource._sort })
 })
```